# How to click a button which looks like this : <input class="btn" onclick="createQuote();" style="margin-top:10px;" value="Create" type="button">

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver and python to try and click this one button which has an element that looks like this:

```
<input class="btn" onclick="createQuote();" style="margin-top:10px;" value="Create" type="button">
```

I've tried a few methods to click on this button like xpath:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
clickCreateQuote = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@title='Create']")))
clickCreateQuote.click()
```

or `find_element_by_id` and `find_element_by_name` - but none of them worked, what else can I look at?

Comment: Please do not mention HTML in the title itself.

Comment: try using class name **driver.findElement(By.className("btn")).click();**

Answer (score 0):

OK - looks like I got it to work, for future reference, this is a button which calls a Javascript event - I used xpath to locate the table ID, the code eventually looked like this:
`clickCreateQuote = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*@id="createQuoteBtnsTbl"]/tbody/tr/td/input')`

To find the table ID, when inspecting the element in Firefox, I had to trace up the tree structure to find all the related elements. In this case, the structure looked like this:
[Iinspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNfgM.png)